# Emacs preview-latex to format python comments and docstrings

Tags: python, emacs, latex

One of my favorite features of Emacs is the preview-latex package: it renders LaTeX equations in LaTeX documents as an inline graphic. Like this:

[image: preview-latex screenshot]

I'd like similar functionality in Emacs for Python comments and function docstrings. My docstrings have a lot of math in them:

```
def proj_levenberg(x,y,wsqrt,A):
    """
    Finds a homography between two sets of 2d points.

    Specifically, approximately minimize the weighted image plane
    error

       min_A  sum_{X,y,w}  w  ||(A_12 x_) /  (A_3 x_)  -  y||^2

    where x_=[x;1], A_12 are the first two rows of A and A_3 is the
    third row of A.
    ...
```

I'd like to write these in LaTex so that I when I browse my code, I can see rendered docstrings and comments.

Is there a way to do this or do I have to do surgergy on preview-latex?

Comment: didn't know about sphinx, andreas. thanks. but i'm looking for rendered equations in my python source while i'm editing it. sphinx is to what i want what preview-latex is to pdflatex.

Comment: I needed something like that for doxygen comments. Since I like preview-mode much more than cdlatex from org-mode I did the surgery of the preview-package. The result is there: https://github.com/TobiasZawada/texfrag/blob/master/texfrag.el . The package is written such that it can easily be adapted to other major-modes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I modified your code sample a bit so that emacs understands what portion of that needs to be replaced with latex fragments:

```
def proj_levenberg(x,y,wsqrt,A):
    """
    Finds a homography between two sets of 2d points.

    Specifically, approximately minimize the weighted image plane
    error

       \(min_A  sum_{X,y,w}  w  ||(A_12 x_) /  (A_3 x_1)  -  y||^2\)

    where \(x_1\)=[x;1], \(A_{12}\) are the first two rows of A and \(A_3\) is the
    third row of A.
    """
```

Note that I have wrapped the latex fragments between `\(` and `\)` [Source](http://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-fragments.html)

You need to have org mode installed. Org is installed by default in emacs but I have the latest org mode installed (version 8.0+) using the emacs package manager.

I have the following in my emacs setup for previewing latex fragments:

```
;; Previewing latex fragments in org mode
(setq org-latex-create-formula-image-program 'imagemagick) ;; Recommended to use imagemagick

(load "auctex.el" nil t t)
(load "preview-latex.el" nil t t)
(setq LaTeX-command "latex -shell-escape")
```

[My org mode setup for emacs](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/master/setup-files/setup-org.el)

[My latex setup for emacs](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/master/setup-files/setup-latex.el)

With this setup when I do `M-x org-preview-latex-fragment`, I get the below. You can remove the previews using `M-x org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c` **Note that I don't need to have the major mode to be `org-mode`.** This function worked even where the buffer was in Python mode and the file was temp.py.

*The catch is that this function will have to be run every time you re-open that file; emacs does not save the preview state of each file.*

[image: Latex fragment preview]

Comment: This worked well, but the previews were black on white, not nicely suited to the theme that I was using (as in your image). Any suggestions for how I can fix this?

Comment: @weemattisnot The previews will always be black-on-white if you set `org-latex-create-formula-image-program` to `'dvipng`. If it is set to `'imagemagick` as in my case, I believe that the preview colors change with theme. I am using the `zenburn` theme and it works fine.

Comment: I have that line in my `.emacs` file. I couldn't figure out what was wrong, but I did find the px-preview package which provided the (minimal) functionality that I needed, a command `px-toggle` that toggles between previewing latex as images and not.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, there's a function in preview-latex that you can call to say "render the text between START and END as a LaTeX formula".  If you ask David Kastrup, he'll tell you what that function is.  So what's left to do is to detect which parts of your code you want rendered this way.